# How to create a FORM in outlook email message

Tags: html, email, templates, outlook

I'm working on creating an Outlook email template that will contain a Form with some fields like name, no, date, price and these fields will be mandatory so validation is required. I know how to create an Outlook Email Message Template using the Outlook Tools, but I want to know how to create a form with some fields and validation.

Answer (score 2):

- Customize the ribbon in outlook to show developer ribbon.
- Then click "design a form". Choose your template, or another.
- In the field chooser, click **New...**. Create the field
- Drag the field into the template. Right click the dragged in field and click properties. Click the validation tab and take it from there

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Actually I want to create a Form in the Message area as Email Template no in the INBOX area ?

Comment: try this link [link]http://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/02/20/create-email-templates-outlook/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic. Tried to do this, but can't get the field to appear in the body of the email. It keeps showing up to the left of the message, but is not include in the boxy when it is delivered. TIA!

Comment: This is not really an answer; may be better to instead leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Outlook will not run any script or submit HTML forms in the messages it displays.